# Autogenerating WPF/Silverlight Views (scaffolding)

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Are there any tools out there to autogenerate the different components used to make up a WPF application?  Model, View, View Model, XAML form?

Comment: what do you wish to generate them from?

Comment: I would like to genertae them from either a model (UML model of some sort, I think VS2010 supports this) or from the database (not ideal but would do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I have found is this:

http://sculpture.codeplex.com/

I am sure that I could knock something up with T4 templates.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to this I've seen to this is the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you `DevExpress` , you can generate your view models and views, for views, you can also use user control for sharing needs.

https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theonewith/archive/2013/06/14/new-wpf-mvvm-scaffolding-wizard-released-in-v2013-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm using T4 templates for View, ViewModel generation in silverlight. I'm using reflection over the Model and generating whole MVVM that way.